# Is there a way to use history with HashRouter, with react-router v4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have need to redirect a user outside of a React component, which typically is done using `history` with react-router.

```
// history.js
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;

// App, setting up router
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';
...
<HashRouter history={history}>...</HashRouter> // problem

// Non-component file
import history from './history';
history.push('/target');
```

Since `HashRouter` doesn't take a history prop, but rather handles history internally, and developers are directed to use `withRouter` in order to expose `history` to a component, it's not apparent how to do redirects outside of a component.

I am using `HashRouter` *and* I need to use the `history` outside of a component (meaning I can't use `withRouter`).

How could I make this happen?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there is a way to use `history` and a hash-based router together.

When creating a history instance, use `createHashHistory` instead of `createBrowserHistory`.

```
// myCreatedHistory.js
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
export default createHashHistory();
```

Instead of using `HashRouter`, use the low-level `Router` instead, and pass the `history` props to it, like so.

```
// App
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../myCreatedHistory';
...
<Router basename="/" history={history}>...</Router>
```

Then you can import the `history` from anywhere (say a middleware).

```
// Middleware, or anywhere
import history from '../myCreatedHistory';
history.push('/target');
```

Comment: it only routed to the desired url but the there was no update in the ui, it show blank page

Comment: This solution also works for react-router v6 (I used it with redux-first-history)